# ThreeVR (ThreeJS) How to replace Y rotation on camera quaternion?

Tags: rotation, three.js, quaternions

I'm using threeVR to make a 360 panorama. It uses mobile device orientation to rotate the camera inside a sphere and also allows the user to manually drag the sphere on touch.

However, when user releases the touch, camera jumps back to device rotation. I want to modify this behavior so that when the user releases the touch, the camera keeps the current rotation around Y axis (but not X and Z).

I do not understand the math of quaternions, but I tried modifying the method updateDeviceMove on [DeviceOrientationController.js](https://github.com/richtr/threeVR/blob/master/js/DeviceOrientationController.js) to add the following code and it did work for Y axis, but messed Z axis.

```
// manuallyMoved is a flag that I set to true on touchend event
// objQuat is the rotation of the camera after user dragged the view 
// deviceQuat is the rotation to be applied, obtained from device orientation values
// The code below replaces the line:
// this.object.quaternion.copy( deviceQuat );

if( manuallyMoved ) {
    objY = rotation.setFromQuaternion( objQuat, 'YXZ' ).y;
    realY = rotation.setFromQuaternion( deviceQuat, 'YXZ' ).y;
    manQuat = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), (objY - realY) );
    deviceQuat.multiply( manQuat );
    manuallyMoved = false;
}else{
    this.object.quaternion.slerp( deviceQuat, 0.07 );
}
```

Since the code messed with Z value, I assume setFromAxisAngle is probably not the way to do it. How can I modify deviceQuat to apply the dragged Y rotation, but allow the camera to use device orientation from there?

Here's a [link to my demo](http://ec2-54-207-23-212.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/tests/360/) using a random image.

Comment: Consider using `THREE.DeviceOrientationControls`, which is compatible with the current version of the library, to control the camera. Then rotate the sphere on its y-axis separately using the touch events as in http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_cube.html.

Comment: I've tried DeviceOrientationControls and encountered similar problems, but I'll have a look at the example you cite